# Magento 2 Api/Data, When To Create It?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, curl

I have fairly simple REST API request to get guest country code by his ip.
In my block file this works perfectly fine when using curl:

```
    $url = "http://........./".$guestIp."?access_key=".$access_key.$jsonOutput;
    $this->_curl->get($url);
    $response = $this->_json->unserialize($this->_curl->getBody());
    $countryCode = $response['country_code'];

    return $countryCode;
```

Now when should I create Api/Data interfaces, repository interfaces in this case if it is needed?

Comment: the purpose of a API and Data repository is to hide the storage related logic.
A client of a repository should not care whether the returned entity is held in memory in an array, is retrieved from a MySQL database, fetched from a remote API or from a file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, the purpose of a repository is to **hide the storage related logic**.

- A client of a repository should not care whether the returned entity
  is held in memory in an array, is retrieved from a `MySQL database`,
  fetched from a remote `API` or from a `file`.
- If a third party module use only the **repositories**, Magento can
  change how and where data is stored, and the module will continue to
  work, despite these deep changes.
- Repositories generally have methods like `findById()`,
  `findByName()`, `put()` or `remove()`.
- In Magento these commonly are called `getbyId()`, `save()` and
  `delete()`, not even pretending they are doing anything else but wrap
  CRUD DB operations.

Magento 2 repository methods can easily be exposed as **API resource**s, making them valuable for integrations with third party systems or **headless Magento instances**.

---

- With service contracts usage (Api/Data interfaces), it will be
  possible to expose custom module functionality as web API just by
  adding config `etc/webapi.xml`
- Improved capabilities for integration with 3rd party systems based on
  service contracts will be added in the future, as well as queue
  support.
- If there is another module dependent on your module, it can just rely
  on service interfaces. This **reduces coupling** between modules and
  minimizes risk of accidental breaking of dependent module.

[image]

> Now when should I create Api/Data interfaces, repository interfaces in
>   this case if it is needed?

- Service contracts enhance the modularity of Magento. They enable
  Magento and third-party developers to report system dependencies
  through **composer.json** files and, consequently, guarantee
  compatibility among Magento versions. This compatibility ensures that
  merchants can **easily upgrade Magento.**
- Data entities are a side benefit of service contracts. The database
  tables that normally support these entities can be complicated. For
  example, some attributes might be stored in an EAV table, so a set of
  MySQL database tables might define a single data entity . Data
  entities in a service contract reveal a simpler data model than the
  data model in an underlying relational database schema . Eventually,
  you will be able to use different storage technologies for different
  data collections. For example, you could use a NoSQL database to
  replace product tables.
- **Using the `@api` tag** - Backward compatibility can be indicated by the use of @api. For more
  information, see **[Backward compatibility.](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/versioning/dependencies.html)**

> **Magento 2 Api/Data, When To Create It?**

As always, the answer is “It depends”. (In [Vinai Kopp](http://vinaikopp.com/2017/02/18/magento2_repositories_interfaces_and_webapi/)'s words)

1. If your entities will be used by other modules, then yes, you
   probably want to add a repository.
2. There is another factor that should be added into the equation: in
   Magento 2, repositories can easily be exposed as Web API - that is
   REST and SOAP - resources.
3. If that is interesting to you because of third party system
   integrations or a headless Magento setup, then again, yes, you
   probably want to add a repository for your entity.

> For more Information

1. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-contracts.html
2. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-to-web-service.html
3. http://vinaikopp.com/2017/02/18/magento2_repositories_interfaces_and_webapi/